# struct/method not working

Tags: c++, console-application

I'm trying to return values in a struct after certain conditions the values are initialised as zero but for some reason they don't increment when the condition is met. I'm brand new to c++ and VS so haven't quite got a grip of how to use the debugger properly. I have checked that the values do in fact initialise to zero. I'm assuming the problem must stem from the input to the SubmitGuess method which should take in a string but must not be for some reason failing that the if statements must be incorrect. Sorry my code is riddled with commented out code, comments and is not complete so please ignore that there is code that should be moved or removed etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated and apologies for posting so much code thought it would be easier to just show you rather than trying to explain.

I should also explain I'm using UE4's recommended data types so whenever you see FString it's just a string same with int32 just an int

```
#include "FISOGame.h"
#include <iostream>
using int32 = int;



//constructor
FGame::FGame()
{
    //initialising the private variables so they don't return with an error
    //MyCurrentTries = 1;
    //MaxTries = 3;
    Reset();
}

void FGame::Reset()
{
    MyCurrentTries = 1;
    MaxTries = 7;
    const FString MyHiddenWord = "cat";
    return;
}


int FGame::GetMaxTries() const
{

    return MaxTries; // gets private variable from header file and returns it
}

int FGame::GetCurrentTries() const
{

    return MyCurrentTries;
}

bool FGame::IsGameWon() const
{
    // TODO check if game is won
    return false;
}

bool FGame::CheckGuessValidity(FString)
{
    // TODO check if guess makes sense
    return false;
}

// recieves a valid guess, increments turn and returns count
BullCowCount FGame::SubmitGuess(FString Guess)
{
    // increment the turn number
    MyCurrentTries++;
    // setup a return value
    BullCowCount BullCowCount;


    // get length of hidden word
    int32 HiddenWordLength = MyHiddenWord.length();

    //loop through all letters of the guess
        //compare letters against hidden word
            // if they match then 
                //increment bulls if there in the same place
                // increment cows id not
            FString Attempt = Guess;

    for (int32 MHWChar = 0; MHWChar < HiddenWordLength; MHWChar++) {
        for (int32 GChar = 0; GChar < HiddenWordLength; GChar++) {
            if (Attempt[GChar] == MyHiddenWord[MHWChar]) {

                if (MHWChar == GChar) {
                    BullCowCount.Bulls++;
                }
                else {
                    BullCowCount.Cows++;
                }
            }
        }
    }



    return BullCowCount;
}
```

---

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using FString = std::string;
using int32 = int;
//never use using namespace in header file


//struct same as class only variables are defaulted public
// variables initialised to 0
struct BullCowCount {
    int32 Bulls = 0;
    int32 Cows = 0;
};

class FGame {
public:
    //constructor make by reusing class name
    // when create instance of class it looks for a constructor and runs whatevers in it
    FGame(); 
public:
    int32 GetMaxTries() const; // const if you don't want the method to change anything
    int32 GetCurrentTries() const;
    void Reset();
    bool IsGameWon() const;
    bool CheckGuessValidity(FString);
    // TODO create method fro counting bulls and cows and increasing turn number
    BullCowCount SubmitGuess(FString);



private:
    // have to initialise the value to avoid error as it's not been created add comment and recompile to get actual value
    // it doesn't pick up the change in the compiler
    //see constructor for initialisation
    int32 MyCurrentTries; 
    int32 MaxTries;
    FString MyHiddenWord;
};
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "FISOGame.h"

using FText = std::string;
using int32 = int;

//using namespace std; // Don't use using namespace as it makes it difficult to see whats included

// create reference or call for function Game_Ask above the main function or wherever it is called
// must put data type for original function before call this makes it a reference and loads it in to memory first
// same thing as declaring functions in a header file

    void Game_Intro();
    FText Game_Guess();
    void Game_loop();

    // make game instance doing this at the top so that it's global and can be accessed by all the functions
    // then you can call this instance (NewGameInst) and add a dot to access it functions
    FGame NewGameInst; // create an instance of or instantiate // made game but don't know it's data or things it holds


// Entry point for application run

int main() {

    Game_Intro();
    Game_loop();


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}



// create function to ask questions declare it outside main 
// Either create above call or reference above main to keep main at top 

void Game_Intro() {

    // introduce the game
    constexpr int32 WORD_LENGTH = 6;


    std::cout<< "Welcome to guess the ISO word" << std::endl;
    std::cout<< "can you guess the " << WORD_LENGTH << " letter ISO word I'm thinking of" << std::endl;

    /* // get a guess from the user
    FText Guess = "";
    std::cout<< "Enter your guess" << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, Guess);
    std::cout<< "Your guess was " << Guess << std::endl; */


    return;

}

FText Game_Guess() {

    int32 CurrentGuesses = NewGameInst.GetCurrentTries(); // gets the current try
    //std::cout << CurrentGuesses << std::endl; // print the current try

    // get a guess from the user
    FText Guess = "";
    std::cout << "Attempt number : " << CurrentGuesses  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Make a guess" << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, Guess);
    return Guess;

}

void Game_loop() {

    // make game instance
    //FGame NewGameInst; // create an instance of or instantiate // made game but don't know it's data or things it holds
    int32 TRIES = NewGameInst.GetMaxTries(); // replaces need for the constant TRIES vvvv
    // constexpr int32 TRIES = 5; // number of tries variable
    std::cout << TRIES << std::endl;


    // loops for number of avaiable guesses
    // TODO change it from for to while loop
    for (int32 Guesses = 1; Guesses <= TRIES; Guesses++) {

        FText Guess = Game_Guess();

        // TODO Submit valid guess to game
        BullCowCount BullsCows = NewGameInst.SubmitGuess(Guess);// submit guess and place in to instance of struct BullCowCount
        // TODO Print number of bulls and cows

        std::cout << "Bulls : " << BullsCows.Bulls;
        std::cout << " Cows : " << BullsCows.Cows << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        //std::cout<< "Your guess was : " << Guess << std::endl; // TODO make loop for checking valid answer
        //std::cout<< std::endl;



        if (Guesses == TRIES) {

            std::cout<< "Nice try sorry you're out of guesses" << std::endl;

            FText Answer = " ";
            std::cout<< "would you like another go? : Y/N " << std::endl;
            std::getline(std::cin, Answer);

            if (Answer == "Y" || Answer == "y") {
                NewGameInst.Reset();
                Game_loop();
            }
            else {
                std::cout<<  "Thanks for playing" << std::endl;
            }



        }

    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: What exactly _doesn't work_? Do you have compiler errors, runtime errors, unexpected output? Also don't ask us to ignore something from your code please, it's on your behalf to present a [MCVE] here.

Comment: Looking through your code it appears that you're creating a new instance but are adding to the temporary instance that's created when the function is called...

Comment: It all compiles fine and works as expected, you enter a guess and it prints out what the guess was. However it should be telling me how many of the letters match the set word and how many are right letters in the wrong place if that makes any sense. Basically the for loop and if statements in SubmitGuess are not working as expected. Sorry I know my code is a bit all over the place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can spot one issue. May not be your only issue.  But here's a fix to start with.

Your Reset method defines a local variable of `MyHiddenWord` which gets discarded when `Reset` returns.  The actual member variable of the `FGame` class, `MyHiddenWord`, never gets initialized.

```
void FGame::Reset()
{
    MyCurrentTries = 1;
    MaxTries = 7;
    const FString MyHiddenWord = "cat"; // this is just a local variable
    return;
}
```

I suspect you meant this:

```
void FGame::Reset()
{
    MyCurrentTries = 1;
    MaxTries = 7;
    MyHiddenWord = "cat";  // actually initializes the member variable of FGame
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou that was the problem could you maybe explain a little bit more as I'm really new to C++.

Comment: Oh sorry I was being slow I get why this has happened now thanks again for the help much appreciated